# IK rotates the wrong direction

Tags: animation, armature

I'm trying to fix a IK-rotation problem. 
When I set the pole angle to -90° my model has the correct leg rotation (pic 1), but when I tried to move the model the knees rotated wrong (pic 2). When I set the pole angle to 180° the knee rotation is correct, but the model not.
I don't know what to do. I rotated the bones in all direction and deleted/created parents between model and bones, but nothing worked.

Can somebody help please? Do you need further informations?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bone limits seem to be missing

Comment: Check your bones' roll in edit mode, that caused me quite a bit of grief in my first few Armatures.

Comment: The limits for IK in Bones doesn't really help. But with a new bone constraint "Limit Rotation" with limit in X = 0 and convert to "Pose Space" it worked. Maybe not the best solution. Thanks VRM. (Checked the bones' roll for 2 days, but couldn't fix it. But thanks for the tip pie75.